# Are upvotes counted retroactively for retagged posts?

Tags: support, tag-badges

Let's say I have posted an answer on a question, that answer got 50 upvotes. Sweet.

Next, the question was retagged, and [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) was added to it.

Will those 50 upvotes be counted towards my badge on [tag](/questions/tagged/tag)? Or would only new upvotes on my answer count? Or perhaps the answer wouldn't be counted on the [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) because it wasn't there in the first place?

Could anyone please clarify this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they will count towards it. But tag scores are not recalculated until 03:00 UTC.

Comment: And it also works the other way. A tag gets removed: you lose the tag score :(